# Realtime advertisements - Selecting ads based on current events (Yahoo!) - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, online-advertising, yahoo, us20130159094a1

**AN OVERBROAD PATENT ON online ads based on current events** - This application from [Yahoo! Inc.](http://www.yahoo.com) seeks to patent the idea of...Identifying current events, categorizing them, and showing ads based on the current event! 10 minutes of your time can help narrow US patent applications before they become patents.  [Follow @askpatents](https://twitter.com/AskPatents) on twitter to help.

**QUESTION** - Have you seen anything that was **published before 12/14/2011** that discusses:

> - Real-time ads triggered by current events

If so, please submit evidence of prior art as an answer to this question. We welcome multiple answers from the same individual.

**EXTRA CREDIT** - Current events such as earthquakes, fires, or floods, **drop in prices** or **sale for a particular type of product** (e.g., cars), a general **reduction in inventory** of a particular type of product, etc.

**TITLE: Showing ads based on current events**

**Summary**:  [Translated from Legalese into English] Identify a current event of any kind (examples: earthquakes, fires, or floods, drop in prices or sale for a particular type of product (e.g., cars), a general reduction in inventory of a particular type of product, etc.), categorize the current event, determine an advertisement based on the **category of event** (Halloween is here?  Buy a costume!), and send the advertisement to a user.

- **Publication Number**: [US20130159094 A1](http://www.google.com/patents/US20130159094)
- **Application Number**: US 13/326,033
- **Assignee**: Yahoo! Inc.
- **Prior Art Date**: Seeking prior Art **predating** 12/14/2011
- **Open for Challenge at USPTO:** Open through 12/17/2013
- **Link to Google Prior Art Search** - ["Find Prior Art"](https://www.google.com/patents/related/US20130159094)

**Claim 1** requires each and every step below:

> A method, comprising:
>
> 1. Identifying by a network device an event that has recently occurred;
> 2. Categorizing by the network device the event into a category of events from a plurality of categories;
> 3. Ascertaining by the network device a set of one or more advertisements associated with the category of events;
> 4. Selecting by the network device at least one advertisement from the set of one or more advertisements associated with the category of events; and
> 5. Providing by the network device the at least one advertisement to a user.

In English this means:

> A method, comprising:
>
> 1. Identify an event that has recently occurred;
> 2. Categorizing the event;
> 3. Find one or more advertisements associated with the category of the current event;
> 4. Select an advertisement associated with the category of event; and
> 5. Show the advertisement to a user.

Good prior art would be evidence of a system that did each and every one of these steps prior to 12/14/2011

You're probably aware of ten pieces of art that meet this criteria already... separately, the applicant is claiming A variety of specific types of current events used to trigger ads, such as earthquakes, fires, or floods, **drop in prices** or **sale for a particular type of product** (e.g., cars), a general **reduction in inventory** of a particular type of product, etc

---

**"Method of serving advertisements based on current events" from the Applicant**

[image]

---

*What is good prior art? Please see our [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art).*

*Want to help? Please vote or comment on submissions below. We welcome you to [post your own request for prior art](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request+pre-grant) on other questionable US Patent Applications.*

---

Comment: Don't mean to be nitpicking, but shouldn't 3. rather read "Find one or more advertisements associated with the category of the current event;" or just "Find advertisements..."?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that (among what I'm sure are a million others) a company called `Helihub` has been doing this kind of context sensitive advertising based upon news stories for some time (September 2011):

http://helihub.com/advertising/context-sensitive-advertising/

They seem to focus on helicopter stories but there are categories within that are categorized further.  Advertisements are associated with categories beforehand.  The advertisement is chosen (presumably) from a pool of clients that want their ad placed on an article from this category's page.  The ad is definitely shown to the end-user.

The only thing I wonder about with this service is that it doesn't specifically target the newest of such stories, as it targets all such stories.

(I'm still not sure if this qualifies as decent prior art as I'm very new to this.)